# Can't install Wordpress in WAMP

Tags: html, wordpress, wamp, wampserver

I can't seem to install my downloaded wordpress in my local wamp server.
It giving me this error:
[image]

My filepath is correct (if I understand it correctly):
[image]

What seems to be the problem?
Thanks for future answers!

Comment: get a fresh wordpress and add that into your folder.In  above screen shot its preinstalled somewhere

Comment: fresh wordpress? so installing wordpress is a one time thing?

Comment: Might be your files are corrupt. Download another copy and try it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question. Author tries to create a website using SO community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a permission issue with those particular files. You may want to try resetting the permissions, or overwriting the files in wp-includes with those from a fresh install of the same WP version.

Comment: How do I do that sir? I got the files from an existing website that is currently up and running. I'm not the who develop it but she asked me to edit it. So she gave me the webhost file and I get all files from there using FTP

Comment: can you replace wp-inlcudes folder from download wordpress in google,